# Is there types of google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

i used google analytics for 2 web apps
one is mine and the other one i was given an access to it by someone
,but i found that both are different :
1st one has customization & behavior tabs [image]
2nd does not have these tabs and has another tabs like retention, engagement [image]

why is that ?
is there types of Google analytics or this is related to permissions ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is Universal Analytics and the second is Google Analytics 4. They are two different tracking system, the second is the new one.